# Drupal 7 Apache solr faceted search with OR condition on two fields instead of drill down/AND

Tags: apache, solr, drupal-7, facet

I have a `Drupal 7` website that is running apachesolr search and is using faceting through the facetapi module.

When I use the facets to narrow my searches, everything works perfectly and I can see the filters being added to the search URL, so I can copy them as links (ready-made narrowed searches) elsewhere on the site.

Here is an example of how the apachesolr URL looks after I select several facets/filters:

```
search_url/search_keyword?f[0]=im_field_tag_term1%3A1&f[1]=im_field_tag_term2%3A100
```

Where the 'search_keyword' portion is the text I'm searching for and the `'%3A'` is just the url encoded `':'` (colon).

Knowing this format, I can create any number of ready-made searches by creating the correct format for the URL. Perfect!

However, these filters are always ANDed, the same way they are when using the facet interface. Does anyone know if there is a syntax I can use, specifically in the search URL, to OR my filters/facets? Meaning, to make it such that the result is all entries that contains EITHER of the two filters?

New edit:

I do know how to OR terms for one facet through the URL im_field_tag_term1:(x or y) but I need to know how to apply OR condition between two facets .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the answer to the exact same problem.